# Jquery Post with JSON Response working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I Have a jQuery Post to a PHP page with generates a JSON Response. It successfully generates JSON because I have it display the whole response. But on the .each I cannot get it to alert.  Any Ideas Appreciated. Thank You. The JSON looks like:

```
[{"Part_Field":"Part_Note:3","Part_Value":"ValueofPart"},{"Part_Field":"Ft_In:3","Part_Value":"12"}, ...
```

jQuery:

```
 $.post('/scripts/update_detail.php' , field_id + "=" + value, function(data){
              var d = document.getElementById("displayjson");
                d.innerHTML = data;

               $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                  alert( value.Part_Field );
                });


   });
```

Comment: Are you sure the jQuery knows it is JSON? `console.log(typeof data);` Does it show string?

Comment: `console.log(data)`, see if it is a string or an array. Unless the `Content-Type` header is `application/json`, it's probably a string.

Comment: Thank You, It was a string. I had to run jQuery.parseJSON on the data to a new variable. Appreciate the Help!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the string `},"json");` in the end.

The corrected code should be:

```
 $.post('/scripts/update_detail.php' , field_id + "=" + value, function(data){
              var d = document.getElementById("displayjson");
                d.innerHTML = data;

               $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                  alert( value.Part_Field );
                });


   },"json"); // Here, you need to tell jQuery that whatever response
// we are getting from server is a JSON string, in your case, 
//it was considering it as a string.
```